# Cron for delete Video not found

Tags: php, mysql

I want make a cronjob that checks all youtube video links added to my website and remove them if they're not found.

I have this code:

```
$headers = get_headers("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$row['youtube']);

if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) 
{
    echo "Video is not found";
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How does responses looks like when there is video and when video is removed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure PHP then save this as, for example, my_cron.php and make it reachable by HTTP. Then create a cronjob and point it to yoursite.com/my_cron.php and set desired interval. Depending of your server settings, cronjob setup may be different. The easiest way is to do it with cPanel, ISPConfig, Kloxo etc.

Comment: yes... but you can give me an exemple how writte the code of the cron.php?

Comment: Cron will just execute your PHP script in some interval, for basic usage you don't need to "code" the cronjob. Checkout this: http://crontab-generator.org/ In your PHP script, just trigger the delete funcion. From your example and provided code, I can't help you more.

Comment: i need the script not the cronjob service :(

Comment: Learn how to use StackOverflow